# Rails 4 asset host boostrap 3 glyphicons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Amazon CloudFront as the asset host for my rails app.

The problem I have is that Glyphicons in Bootstrap 3 are not being displayed.

I'm using:

```
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',
    :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails'
```

The glyphicons displayed prior to using CloudFront as the asset host.  I'm assuming that the glypicons are trying to be served by CloudFront.

Is there a way to prevent the glypicons from being served from CloudFront or to get them to display using CloudFront.

Thanks.

Comment: what are [these line](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/twitter/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss#L11-L18) compiling into?, then compare it to where the font's are actually located.

Comment: okay weird, my assets are compiled to my staging cloudfront, but the glypicons are using my production cloudfront.